# Obtener un campo específico de la base de datos con Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener un campo específico de una tabla de la base de datos.

Supongamos que tengo un campo llamado `value`, y al hacer mi `get` me queda así.

```
$this->db->where('variable', $variable);
$query = $this->db->get('w_settings', 1);
```

ahora quiero saber como puedo obtener el campo llamado `value` y poder retornarlo dentro de mi modelo.

Comment: Hola! tienes 2 preguntas mas, las cuales no marcaste como aceptadas. Si las respuestas no te sirvieron por favor aclara que cosas faltan para que esten completas. De paso, si no lo hiciste, haz el [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que obtener el valor de la fila y devolver el value:

```
$this->db->where('variable', $variable);
$query = $this->db->get('w_settings', 1)->row();
return $query->value;
```

Como ves, he añadido el **row()**. Con ello, obtienes la primera fila del resultado de la query en formato objeto. Después, podemos acceder a ese atributo del objeto con **$query->value.**

Si lo prefieres, puedes usar *row_array()* y acceder como *$query['value'].*

Tienes más información en la documentación de CodeIgniter:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html

Además, y como info, si lo que quieres es solo tener ese "value" y no todos los campos de la tabla, puedes añadir un select:

```
$this->db->select('value');
$this->db->where('variable', $variable);
$query = $this->db->get('w_settings', 1)->row();
return $query->value;
```

Con esto evitarás tener que pedir todos los campos si realmente solo necesitas uno.